# Schedule Wordpress plugin activation and / or deactivation on a custom date and time, how to do?

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for two snipped code example, one for a plugin activation on a specific date (and if is possibile time) and the other one for a plugin deactivation date (and if possibile time).

In the example code I just need to know how can I find the plugin string and where the plugin string need to be replaced in the code.

The snipped code should, for example, deactivate a plugin the day 7 January 2024 after 15:00 PM

I never found an example of code ready to be used with examplined just places that I need to replace to make it work.. and how, where I can take the right plugin string to put in the code. The plugin string that will identify the plugin to activate or deactivate.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it your own plugin? You could just wrap the init code in a date & time check, and e.g. add an admin_notice explaining why it's temporarily disabled and when it will be back.

Comment: Usually actually wholly deactivating and activating a plugin to control functionality like this is not the appropriate way to go about it. What plugin do you need to deactivate and what functionality do you need to stop at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something that WordPress supports out of the box, but I think you can whip up some custom code to achieve this.

I think you can use WordPress cron job that will check the current date and time for this to activate/deactivate the plugin accordingly.

Here's an example for deactivating:

```
add_action('wp', 'plugin_deactivation_schedule');
function plugin_deactivation_schedule() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('custom_deactivate_plugin')) {
        // Schedule to run on 7th January 2024, at 15:00
        $timestamp = strtotime('2024-01-07 15:00:00');
        wp_schedule_single_event($timestamp, 'custom_deactivate_plugin');
    }
}

add_action('custom_deactivate_plugin', 'deactivate_my_plugin');

function deactivate_my_plugin() {
    // Replace with your plugin string
    $plugin = 'my-cool-plugin/my-cool-plugin.php';

    if (is_plugin_active($plugin)) {
        deactivate_plugins($plugin);
    }
}
```

For the activation one, you can follow the same snippet and just change the last set of if condition to check if the plugin is not activated, you activate it.

```
if (!is_plugin_active($plugin)) {
     activate_plugin($plugin);
}
```

About the plugin string, you can find it in your plugin files. For example, if your plugin's main file is located at wp-content/plugins/your-custom-plugin/your-custom-plugin.php, the plugin string would be your-custom-plugin/your-custom-plugin.php.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and let you know :)

Comment: IT works on my VPS, doesn't work on Aruba hosting, maybe I set time to be 23:55 and I need set a early time as the cron is run slower. The code seems works as in my VPS is good, thanks.

Comment: And if I want run the code every year so day, month but not specify year?

Comment: You'll have to manipulate the dates so that you can check which date it will run next time. That way, you can run it every year if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found that insert the date like 7-Jen resolve the date issue. Thanks again for your precious help :)